# While loop in case statement (C++)

Tags: c++

Is anyone can help me resolve I think trivial issue for someone who knows C langue quite well.
I have some piece of code however label_start_menu: doesn't work for me.
What I want to achieve is back to default: Now if e.g. 3 == 3 while loop is working infinite and is not possible to return to default:

```
  switch (counter1) {

  case 1:

    menu_clock();
    delay(2000);

    while(true){

      Serial.println("loop1");
      Serial.println("loop1");
      Serial.println("loop1");

      if(3 == 3)
      {
        break;
       goto label_start_menu;
      }  
    }
    break;

  case 2: 

    menu_media();
    delay(2000);
    break;

  default:
label_start_menu:
    menu_start();
    break;
  }
}
```

Thanks,
ojdas

Comment: What exactly is using `3 == 3` as an `if` predicate doing for you?

Comment: `goto` - I haven't seen that for years! Also, what are you hoping to gain from `if ( 3 == 3 )` - three is always going to be, well, three.

Comment: What's with the `3 == 3` thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
  if(3 == 3)
  {
    break;
    goto label_start_menu;
  }
```

`goto` will never get executed because the `break` statement will break out of your loop right there.

My advice would be to get rid of the `goto`, and to just call `menu_start()` in the if statement, and then break,  instead of using a goto.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your while loop, exactly, but you've got your `break;` statement in front of your `goto label_start_menu;` statement, so it will never be reached.

More complete answer: there's absolutely no need for the goto in the first place.  You're already calling another function.  Rewrite the whole thing like this:

```
switch (counter1)
{
case 1:
    menu_clock();
    delay(2000);
    Serial.println("loop1");
    Serial.println("loop1");
    Serial.println("loop1");
    menu_start();
    break;

case 2: 
    menu_media();
    delay(2000);
    break;

default:
    menu_start();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the break should be the last thing..

also, why put it in a loop? that is an infinite loop..  just call it and then break breaking will get you out of the switch and will not continue so make sure you do everything before you break, so put your `goto label_start_menu;` before the break and remove the if statement and the other break under it.

if you want to loop it then there are other loop methods you can use.. google is great with that!

Answer (score 0):

Im going to repost [@40two's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27452122/1413395), because it exactly hits the nail about usage of `goto` (besides the other flaws coming in the same way (no reasonable loop break conditions)).

[image]

@40two: [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/) is a real good source for insight, as lomg you're able to read it!